# Django collect elements from database

Tags: python, html, database, django, project

I'm in trouble with adding goals from the same footballer in every matches.

I've got classes

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Footballer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    name_team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Match(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    who = models.ForeingKey(Team,related_name="as_host")
    guest = models.ForeingKey(Team,related_name="as_guest")

class Footballer_stat(models.Model):
    id_footballer = models.ForeignKey(Footballer)
    scored_goals = models.IntegerField('Strzelone Bramki')
```

And I use view from view.py which looks like :

```
def how_much_goals(request):
    x = Footballer.objects.all()
    z = Footballer_stat.objects.order_by('-scored_goals') 
    sum = Pilkarz_stat.objects.aggregate(Sum("scored_goals"))

    return render_to_response("goals.html",{"footballer":x,"footballer_goals":z, "Shooted_goals":sum["scored_goals__sum"]})
```

Then in goals.html I want to collect all names with goals from EVERY matches like

```
Footballer Goals      Results of adding goals the same ballers
    Xxxx     2            Xxxx 3
    Yyyy     3      (+)   Yyyy 4
    Xxxx     1      --->
    Yyyy     1
```

What I should do to achieve the desired effect ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I hope your DB is denormalized on purpose and if it's already denormalized, why dont you just put the column `scored_goals` into the `Fooballer` table? btw `with` is a reserved keyword so you might have a problems with it

Comment: Because I write project in study and it should look like that. The name with I changed to guest. Everything works in this database (I add a lot of elements and check by writing it on html) but I asked about HOW TO ADD UP ALL GOALS OF EACH PLAYER IN MATCH (like in example )

Comment: sorry your formulation is a bit vague. By 'adding a goal' you mean creating a client code in a template + a server-side view to manage given request, which will increase the value in db or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it `have to look like that`as you said in your comment, then I'm probably not able to help you and you can ignore this answer. If it `doesnt have to look like that`, then the possible solution is something this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Match(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    who = models.ForeingKey(Team,related_name="as_host")
    guest = models.ForeingKey(Team,related_name="as_guest")

class PlayerStats(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    goals = models.IntegerField('Strzelone Bramki')
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('player', 'match')
```

Now you can add a score for each player per match quite easily. Also you need only one `QuerySet` to pass to your template:

```
qs = PlayerStats.objects.select_related().all().extra(Sum('goals'))
qs.group_by = ('player', 'match')
for player in qs:
    qs.player.name # player's name
    qs.goals__sum # goals per match
```

it's a long time since I've worked with Django so it might be inaccurate.

Comment: Firstly I insert elements to database in ADMIN panel.
Secondly I show it on HTML page. And at the end I want operate on my databases (which is completed) and collect statistics like "List of the best scorers", so when I have in example 3 players, in 3 other matches I want collect (summed) every goals from each other like : First Player - 10 (First player scored 10 goals in 3 matches)
Second playes - 5 (Second playes scored 5 goalds in 3 mathes) witohut the information in ( )